# Prove that $ S=\{0\}\cup\left(\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} \{\frac{1}{n}\}\right)$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Prove that $ S=\{0\}\cup\left(\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} \{\frac{1}{n}\}\right)$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$, but $\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} \{\frac{1}{n}\}$ is not a compact set.

(Can we use definition of compact set for this problem? )

Comment: What have you thought about? What have you tried?

Comment: Recall that you are in $\mathbb{R}$, so the compact sets are just the closed and bounded sets.

Comment: I can't find  a finite subcover for $S$.

Comment: I have proved it. Hooray.

Answer (score 1):

We *have* to use the definition of a compact set here. The latter set is not compact since you can come up with its open cover $B(\frac1n,2^{-n})$ which does not have a finite subcover (why?). The former set is compact since it is closed and bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose you have an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $S$. Now at least one $U_\beta$ contains $0$. Then because $1/n \to 0$ this means $U_\beta$ contains all but finitely elements of $S$. Thus.....

Answer (score 0):

You can see that the second set isn't compact, because, we can take the series in this set $ a_n=\frac{1}{n}$, which converges to 0, which isn't in this set. Therefore, according to the definition, this set isn't compact.

The first set is bounded between [0,1], and it's closed, because every series in this set which converges must converge to a number within the set. Therefore it's compact, because it's closed and bounded.